# How can I get a numerical solution with Bessel functions?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to get the series of numerical solutions, with BesselJ functions. which is,

> Solve[x BesselJ[1, x] == t BesselJ[0, x], x]

where t is just some constant. Solve, NSolve, NSolveValues does not work at all. It says

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

How can I get any solutions from the equation? at least some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indicating a range of `x` helps:

```
f[t_?NumericQ] := NSolve[{x BesselJ[1, x] == t *BesselJ[0, x] && x >= -10 && x <= 10}, x]
f[3.3]
```

> `{{x -> -7.4445}, {x -> -4.50817}, {x -> -1.82984}, {x ->  1.82984}, {x -> 4.50817}, {x -> 7.4445}}`

Comment: Thank you. it was truely helpful

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn[t_] = x BesselJ[1, x] == t BesselJ[0, x];
```

As suggested by user64494, for a given `t`, constrain `x` to an interval. However, use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
Solve[{eqn[0], -15 < x < 15}, x] // N // Quiet

(* {{x -> 0.}, {x -> 
   0.}, {x -> -13.3237}, {x -> -10.1735}, {x -> -7.01559}, {x -> -3.83171}, \
{x -> 3.83171}, {x -> 7.01559}, {x -> 10.1735}, {x -> 13.3237}} *)
```

Note that [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) may miss a solution

```
NSolve[{eqn[0], -15 < x < 15}, x]

(* {{x -> -13.3237}, {x -> -10.1735}, {x -> -7.01559}, {x -> -3.83171}, {x -> 
   3.83171}, {x -> 7.01559}, {x -> 10.1735}, {x -> 13.3237}} *)
```

Use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) to see the solutions

```
cp = ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn[t],
   {x, -15, 15}, {t, -5, 5},
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, t})];

Manipulate[
 t = Rationalize[tt, 0];
 sol = x /. Solve[{eqn[t], -15 < x < 15}, x] // Quiet;
 Show[cp,
  Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Tooltip[Point[{#, tt}], N@#] & /@ sol}],
  ImageSize -> Medium],
 {{tt, 0, "t"}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: In fact, `Solve` switches to `NSolve` in the above, producing something like `x -> Root[{   33 BesselJ[0, #] - 10 BesselJ[1, #] #& , -7.44450249554839595179.5}.   ]`. BTW, `t==0` is a special case and there is a command `BesselJZero` to this end.

Comment: Thank you a lot!